# Manipulating string to become half uppercase and half lower case

Tags: python

I got the following homework question:
Write a program that picks up from the string user for selection.
The program prints the string when the letters in the first half of the string are lowercase and the letters in the second half of the string are capital letters.
If the length of the string is odd, the first half will be smaller in one half of the second.

additional instructions:
Do not use loops or if conditions.
Use a slicing action.
Assume that the length of the string is greater than 2.

I used up the following code:

```py
#Input of the text
fullClintStr = input("please enter text: ")
#New str of all the current str just in lower case
lowerCaseStr = fullClintStr.lower()
#New str of all the current str just in upper case
upperCaseStr = fullClintStr.upper();
#Slice from the start to the middle (if str length is odd then it will be included in the first half)
lowerCaseStr = lowerCaseStr[0 : (len(fullClintStr) / 2 + len(fullClintStr) % 2)]
#Slice from middle to the end
upperCaseStr = lowerCaseStr[(len(fullClintStr) / 2 - len(fullClintStr) % 2) : len(fullClintStr)]
#Combine both string to new string that itrs firs half is lower case and the #other is upper case
combinedResultStr = lowerCaseStr + "" + uupperCaseStr
#Print he results
print(combinedResultStr)
```

but faced an error from the type:" slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method"

I would like to know how it can possibly be done. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Well `fullClintStr` is a `str` not an `int` and you are attempting to divide it by `2`...

Comment: typo in  `uupperCaseStr` , also, you're trying to devide a `str` by an `int` in `fullClintStr / 2`, the error is  there.

Comment: slicing is done using the `:` syntax - not the `,` syntax... - you always want integer division rather than true division... here's a hint.. to get the first of your input string into lower case try... `first_half = fullClintStr[:len(fullClinStr) // 2].lower()` ?

Comment: @rahlf23 well I have changed it to len(fullClintStr) in all required places, still not working

Comment: Please update your question with an input example.

Comment: Based on your latest update, I'd advise you to read https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for your needs. Hope it helps:

```
fullClintStr = input("please enter text: ")
strlen = len(fullClintStr)
lowerCaseStr = fullClintStr.lower()
upperCaseStr = fullClintStr.upper()
cutlen = strlen - (strlen//2)
printStr = lowerCaseStr[:cutlen] + upperCaseStr[cutlen:]
print(printStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fullClintStr` is a string and so if you are trying to access substrings using index numbers what you are looking to do is `len(fullClintStr)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is you are trying to use find the middle point of the list but are not actually getting the length of the string. Consider the script below:

```
fullClintStr = input("please enter text: ")
list_string = []

for index, element in enumerate(fullClintStr):
    if len(fullClintStr) % 2 == 0:
        if index < len(fullClintStr)/2:
            list_string.append(element.upper())
        else:
            list_string.append(element.lower())
    else:
        if index < (len(fullClintStr)/2) - 1:
            list_string.append(element.upper())
        else:
            list_string.append(element.lower())

input_string = ''.join(list_string)
print(input_string)
```

By wrapping the string using the len command, we can see what the length of the script is. As you said in your problem, you cannot use loops of if statements to solve the problem, but this should give you an idea on how you should approach finding the middle point.

Comment: as said above, "additional instructions: Do not use loops or if conditions."

Comment: As the first message said, "consider the script below" not this "is the answer". I am not in the business of answering HW questions, but now the OP has an understanding on how to approach the problem. Its up to him to rewrite what I have done without the if/loop